# Draft design of a database

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

Anyone now what is a draft design of a database???
Is it the design process and steps like:

- Determine the purpose of your database
- Find and organize the information required
- Divide the information into tables
- Turn information items into columns
- Specify primary keys
- Set up the table relationships
- Refine your design
- Apply the normalization rules

Or is it something else???
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

A draft of anything is a preliminary (or rough) sketch. It could be a design, picture or document etc..  It is often non-final, and often indicates an iterative process.

Answer (score 0):

Its a loose term depending on what you are doing, if you are planning or analyzing, it might refer to what you mentioned, or it might be a simple throw away prototype of what you think the database would look like and to give you a more tangible feel of your database...

Answer (score 0):

Draft version is something you propose. It is not the finalized version and can be modifed if required. In your case, the draft version must have everything you need to deliver for the database design.